# 2 Equations continuous at a point

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I want to get continuous  point between two equations.

My equations are:

```
To[x_] := 2 c1 Cosh [x Sqrt[((f0 - b g0)/q)]] + g0/(f0 - b g0);


Tu[x_] := 10 Exp[-m x];
```

I try to find c1 and m constants which are in terms of g0.

I have boundary conditions which are;

> ```
> T = Tu   @ x = +L/2
>
> D^2 k T'[x] = Du^2  ku Tu'[x]     @ x = + L/2
> ```

So, I have two uknown "c1,m" and two boundary conditions for single point. It should be continuous at L/2. Actually boundary conditions for +- L/2 ( because cosh is symmetric, but I assume m is positive , so just for positive part of boundary)

Like that plot,for example, he had found Tu= 10.3 e^-598(x-0.005), it is continuous at 0.5 mm with cosh function.

[image]

In the same manner, it should be obtained thanks to boundary conditions.

Then I applied boundary conditions in order to find "c1,m" to be continuous at L/2.

```
Solve[g0/(f0 - b g0) + 2 c1 Cosh[1/2 L Sqrt[(f0 - b g0)/q]] - 
   10 E^(-((L m)/2)) == 0, c1]

{{c1 -> -((
    E^(-((L m)/2)) (-10 f0 + 10 b g0 + E^((L m)/2) g0) Sech[
      1/2 L Sqrt[(f0 - b g0)/q]])/(2 (f0 - b g0)))}}
```

c1 is okay, then for  finding m I applied derivative boundary condition,

```
Solve[2 c1 Sqrt[(f0 - b g0)/q]
     Sinh[1/2 L Sqrt[(f0 - b g0)/q]] dia^2 k - (-10 E^(-((L m)/2))
      m Du^2 ku) == 0, m]
```

And program gave error as:

```
S`olve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.`
```

How can I get c1 and m in terms of g0 ?

When I obtain c1 and m in terms of g0, constant temperature condition will be used for g0:

```
int=Integrate[To[x],{x,-L/2,L/2}]

NSolve[int=220,g0]
```

Comment: I get a warning that it is using inverse functions (so may not find all the answers) but your final `Solve` does give an answer for `m`. Maybe quit the kernel and try again.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it with simplified variable names:

```
To[x_] := 2 c1 Cosh[x a1] + a2
Tu[x_] := 10 Exp[-m x]
bcs = {To[L/2] == Tu[L/2], To'[L/2] == a4 Tu'[L/2]};
s = First@Solve[bcs[[1]], c1]
Quiet@Solve[bcs[[2]] /. s[[1]], m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I was thinking that if I solve for positive part, also the problem will be done for negative part. Because cosh is symmetric. But Tu must be zero at +- Infinity. Because of this reason,I assumed that Tu=10 Exp[-mx], when x is positive it goes zero at +infinity and when x is negative it goes zero at -infinity. I applied your code, it is okay for @ x=L/2  but it not satisfied for @ x=-L/2. Can you help me?

Comment: Why don't use another function to the left (the symmetric one)

Comment: When I put negative number for x, it ise mirror of positive part, isn't it ?